# 3 digit numbers over 700 (non repeating)

Tags: combinatorics

A password uses 3 digits which can't be repeated. How many possible numbers are over 700?

Comment: $701,702,...,987.$ What have you tried? Have you considered the Rule of Product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product?

Comment: 3 choices for the first digit, 9 for the second, 8 for the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the possibilities would be: $P =10\cdot9\cdot8 = 720$

Since the first digit must be equal or greater than $7$ : $P_{>700} = 3\cdot9\cdot8 = \boxed{216}$

Each factor represents the number of possible choices for the corresponding digit. So, the first one have 3 possibilities (7, 8 and 9); the second one will have 9 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and [7 and 8] or [7 and 9] or [8 and 9] -- depending on the first digit); the last one will have 8 (the 8 numbers between 0 and 9 different than the first and second digits).